# Pandas delete rows with Groupby two columns using quartile

Tags: python, pandas, percentile

Good morning all,

I have a problem, I want to delete the lines using a condition on percentile and groupby, example:

for each x, y .. in the column key and for each group of iden a, b, c .. it will delete the elements which are in the first pencetile/quantile and the last one using the function: Min & Max or with .quantile (.1) and. quantile (.9) on val1

Input:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['x', 'a', 9.5, 10.5], ['x', 'b', 6.8, 7], ['y','a', 7.2, 8],
    ['x', 'a', 11.5, 11.5], ['y', 'c', 1.5, 1.5], ['y', 'c', 8.7, 8.7],
    ['x', 'a', 15.5, 1.5], ['y', 'c', 2.5, 2.5], ['y', 'c', 9.5, 1.7]
], columns=['key', 'iden','val','val2'])
df
```

```py
   key  iden val  val2
0   x   a   9.5   10.5
1   x   b   6.8   7.0
2   y   a   7.2   8.0
3   x   a   11.5  11.5
4   y   c   1.5   1.5
5   y   c   8.7   8.7
6   x   a   15.5  1.5
7   y   c   2.5   2.5
8   y   c   9.5   1.7
```

i need to get this result :

```py
    key iden val val2
0   x   b   6.8  7.0
1   y   a   7.2  8.0
2   y   c   8.7  8.7
3   x   a   11.5 11.5
4   y   c   2.5  2.5
```

Comment: Why is (x,a) kept in the output? quantile .1 is 9.9 and quantile .9 is 14.7, so it should be removed right

Comment: I guess (x, a) will be `11.5, 11.5`, Right?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma You are right, it should be 11.5 11.5

Comment: Sorry ,  in this example i used the min & max function , but you have any solution for min max or quantile it's same for me , thank you @DavideBrex

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Sorry in this example i delete min max , but if you have any solution tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
g = df.groupby(['key', 'iden'])['val']
m = df['val'].between(g.transform('quantile', 0.1), g.transform('quantile', 0.9))
df = df[m]
```

Or use:

```
m = (
    df.groupby(['key', 'iden'])['val']
    .transform(lambda s: s.between(s.quantile(0.1), s.quantile(0.9)))
)
df = df[m]
```

---

```
print(df)
  key iden   val  val2
1   x    b   6.8   7.0
2   y    a   7.2   8.0
3   x    a  11.5  11.5
5   y    c   8.7   8.7
7   y    c   2.5   2.5
```